# SQL search for phrases in database aganst body of text

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP + Mysql, I have a database with a table containing small phrases like;

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID | phrase          |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | quick brown fox |
| 2  | slow green      |
| 3  | lazy dog        |
| 4  | ultra hyper cat |
+----+-----------------+
```

Is there a practical and efficient way to query the database with a small body of text such like...

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

and have it return rows 1 and 3? Note; the text in the table is consistently formatted with no punctuation, single spaces, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Once I get to prototyping the solutions below I'll set an accepted answer; Thank you! I'll see if I can add some basic benchmarking info between the answers when I'm done.

Comment: The problem with the answers submitted so far is that they aren't very efficient. Partial text matching won't use indexes, so there will be a full table scan, with a function called on every row. This would be acceptable for small datasets, but not for large ones. The optimal solution will break down stored strings into indexed words, but that's not something I have done before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a full text search

```
SELECT phrase FROM my_tbl WHERE MATCH( phrase ) AGAINST ('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this also :

```
SELECT phrase FROM my_tbl WHERE 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' LIKE CONCAT('%',phrase,'%')
```

Comment: Huh. I didn't know LIKE could have the column placed after the needle. Makes perfect sense though. XD